# Difference in effective length between states is too big. Transition preview will be disabled. UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Делаю 2D платформер. Сделал анимации, всё нарезал, сделал ветви в аниматоре и всё отлично работало, но после у меня случилась проблема и я в пользу своей глупости, случайно удалил все анимации. Решил создать всё по-новому и столкнулся с проблемой. Я менял значение Transition Duration с 0 на 0.1 и ошибка пропадала, но раньше было всё точно также, но ошибки не было. Может я что-то не понимаю? У источника всё точно также. (Ошибка только на определённых ветвях и скриншоты ниже). Сама анимация хорошо работает, но всё же повторюсь - раньше всё было нормально и не было ошибок.

[image: LookRight-TransitionLeft]
[image: LookLeft-TransitionRight]
[image: LookLeft-FallASleep]

Comment: Такое обычно появляется, если переход ведёт в состояние, которому не назначена анимация, либо назначена анимация без кадров.

Comment: @M.Green всё перепроверил, анимации назначены, в каждой анимации есть кадры. (FallASleep - Samples 20, картинок из нарезки 15, TransitionLeft, как и TransitionRight - Samples 14, нарезка 5)